# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found (installed with pecl)

Tags: php, apache, memcached, pecl

I installed memcache via ssh, with:

```
$ pecl install memcache
```

And this was the output: https://pastee.org/w63sy

And added this line to `etc/php.ini`:

```
extension=memcache.so
```

And when trying to initialize:

```
/* MEMCACHE */
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->pconnect('localhost',11211);
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /home/piscolab/public_html/website.com/includes/sql.php on line 25
```

What am I doing wrong?

I found this question but the problem was about his shared server. I am under a VPS.

Running: `php -i | grep php.ini`:

```
[root@vps ~]# php -i | grep php.ini                                                                                                                                            
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o
r directory in Unknown on line 0                                                                                                                                               
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc                                                                                                                                      
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini                                                                                                                                      
[root@vps ~]#
```

Finding memcache.so (no output)

```
[root@vps ~]# find / -type f -name memcache*.so'                                                                                                                              
[root@vps ~]# find / -type f -name memcache*.so                                                                                                                                
[root@vps ~]#
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after adding that line to the config?

Comment: negative! I'll try right now. thanks!

Comment: I restarted the virtual machine and nothing changed @DCoder and /etc/init.d/apache2 restart log me that not such file or directory :S

Comment: That error means your `memcache.so` is *not* in `/usr/lib/php/` - you could try `find /usr/ -name memcache.so` to see where it is.

Comment: @DCoder so how?  'find /myusername/ -name memcache.so' ??

Comment: I installed again: https://pastee.org/w63sy this is the log. i have an error at the end

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet What OS are you running?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Try running `yum install zlib-devel` and then re-running the pecl install command.  On a side note, you may consider installing `Memcached` as this is newer than the `memcache` library and supports more features, but if what you are using needs `memcache`, then just use that.

Comment: As a sanity check, you could try zlib then memcache and make sure it gets past that zlib part first where you got the error, and then try memcached.  It is the same proceduce, `pecl install memcached`.

Comment: That was it! @drew010 post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the output of the error message, it looks like you are missing the `zlib` development libraries, or at least they are not in the usual location where it can be automatically found by configure.

Since you are on CentOS, try installing the libraries with this command:

```
yum install zlib-devel
```

This installs the zlib library which is required for memcache.  Try re-running the pecl installer after installing the zlib libraries.

Answer (score 1):

it will probably help if you give some more info via phpinfo() or php_config, more specifically, does your install see the memcache libs and are your lib paths correct.

```
php-config
```

will tell you more, interesting here are the php ini path used and the lib paths
php ini path will be displayed when you use --configure-options, suboption --with-config-file-path (/etc/php5/apache2 in my specific case)
and the lib paths will be displayed with --extension-dir

e.g.

```
php-config --extension-dir

php-config --configure-options | grep -o 'with-config-file-path[^ ,.]*' | grep -o '[^=.]*$'
```

So to use my example my lib paths are set to

/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs and an

```
ls /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mem*
```

command for my system reveals:

/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/memcached.so

and my php.ini file is located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

the phpinfo() php function (just place  in a file and view it) also reveals memcache as supported and loaded "memcached support  enabled" (I specifically used memcached extension, not memcache)

mind you that your webserver might be configured to use a different php.ini path (and thus file) than your command line, so verify both. Also make sure you place the extension=memcache.so in the correct location, since many distros place it in /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini  might be there's some discrepancy there?

Comment: wow! buddy, thanks for your answer, but i kind of got lost in the way.. i will run the ssh commands you posted and will let you know. but you're basically saying that my php.ini is not the one that apache is  using?

Comment: it might be a possible answer to your problem, yes

Comment: Pleaze check my edit. it seems that it's the right php.ini path but some errors are show, do you understand them?

Comment: like Dcoder said in the comment above: your memcache.so library file can not be found and thus not loaded, check for its existence (as root or precede the comand with sudo) with `find / -type f -name 'memcache*.so'` 

If this command can't find it then you don't have the library file properly installed and you'll need to (re)install memcache php module. Mind you this searches your whole disk so it'll take a while to return to you with an answer, it's a brute force way to be sure, sorry. :)

Comment: if you can actually find memcache.so this way then it's no doubt on a directory that your php doesn't see and you'll need to then add that path to the path for PHP extensions.

Comment: if find just returns you to a prompt without result, with a search starting from /, then that means the correct module is not installed, reinstall the memcache module, probably something went wrong the first time you got it installed.

Comment: i paste: find / -type f -name 'memcache*.so' (and no response/output/error :?)  please check my phpinfo here http://keepyourlinks.com/includes/index1.php

Comment: mind you from that link a) memcache is not installed, 2) your server uses /home/httpd/keepyourlinks.com/php.ini as its ini file

Comment: I installed again, i have an error at the end: https://pastee.org/w63sy would you please have a look and let me know what's wrong? I tried saying 'no' when asking for session handling and error is the same :(

Comment: you need to have the zlib development code installed, on my ubuntu system it's a package called "zlib1g-dev" - compression library - development, just search with your package manager for zlib and install the version with -dev behind it. It might be you lack other -dev packages as well, whenever it complains about something, search for it and install the -dev version. Good luck.