# php-fpm extension listed in phpinfo() fails with "Class not found"

Tags: memcached, php-extension, php

nginx + php-fpm on CentOS, all compiled from sources.
Adding memcached support, I compiled `libmemcached` and php "memcached" extension, added a line `php_admin_value[extension]=memcached.so' in the php-fpm config and restarted php-fpm.

Opening a test php with `phpinfo()` via web server started showing a section about "memcached" extension ([screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/ss.memcached.png)). However attempts to instantiate the class fail with Fatal error: `Class 'Memcached' not found`.

I also tried installing the php "memcache" (*without 'd'*) extension in the same way: downloading sources, `phpize`, `configure`, `make`, `make install`. All the same: [listed](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3533396/SO/ss.memcache.png) in `phpinfo();`, "Class not found" fatal error.

What am I doing wrong, and **how can I add a compiled extension to the php-fpm?**
`yum` / `pecl` package managers are not an option currently, as specific versions are required.

Comment: pecl supports specific versions actually.

Answer (score 1):

You set up seems fine. I have the same set up, except my memcache/memcached are installed by yum. So maybe your memcache/memcached not installed properly. The following link mentions a dependency on zlib-devel.

[Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found (installed with pecl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773524/fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found-installed-with-pecl)

Comment: Sorry, this didn't change anything. My fault testing this as positive first time.

Comment: Did you find any error msg in the php-fpm error log? If you run 'php -m' in command line, did php complain something?